# Which song is played in Akame ga Kill episode 1 at 1.34?

Tags: music, akame-ga-kill

Which song is played in this video at 1:34?
[Akame ga Kill episode 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BqE4mfh5P8)

Answer (score 2):

The song you’re looking for is called “[Le Chant de Roma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igKXRrb5_ts)” by [Taku Iwasaki](http://www.anisearch.com/person/20627,taku-iwasaki).